# Why use .sty files?

Tags: packages, best-practices

Why is it preferable to put inclusions of commonly used packages and user defined commands in a `.sty` file instead of putting them in an ordinary `.tex` file?

Comment: To avoid copy/pasting the same definitions over and over again to each document.

Comment: @percusse: I guess the question is more about the suffix and which one to use – `tex` or `sty` or even `cls` …

Comment: Is it possible to `\input` or `\include` a `tex` file on the preamble?

Comment: @percusse I think he's trying to compare a separate `.tex` file with only the commonly used commands as opposed to defining a new style using `.sty` files.

Comment: @Sigur -- it is certainly possible to `\input` a file in the preamble.  however, `\include` always starts a new page, an action that is *not* permitted in the preamble, only after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Tobi @recluze Indeed, I took the *ordinary `.tex` file* phrase  the wrong way.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

First of all: *never* use `\include` to load a file with personal definitions and packages to use.

The choice is thus between `\input` and `\usepackage`; for the first it's better to use the extension `.tex` for the file, for the second `.sty` is mandatory.

What are the pros of the latter solution? Many. For instance you can define *options* that can change the behavior of your macros or selectively load parts of it (see example below).

In a `.sty` file `@` is assumed to be a letter, so no `\makeatletter` or `\makeatother` command is needed to access "private macros", which is often the case for complex macros.

If you don't need options nor access to private macros, loading your definitions and package with `\input{mymacros}` is exactly equivalent to `\usepackage{mymacros}` (provided that the file is `mymacros.tex` in the first case and `mymacros.sty` in the second one).

As noticed by Andrew Stacey, there is one more pro in using a `.sty` file: it won't be loaded twice, even if called twice in a document (maybe frome some other loaded file or package). This is important because `\newcommand` would raise errors on the second loading (and other definitions might lead to infinite loops).

**Example:**
Suppose you have a macro that must change its behavior when the `draft` option is enabled in the `\documentclass` line; for instance it should have an argument that's emphasized in the text and is also written in the margin for draft copies.

```
\ProvidesPackage{mymacros}
\newif\if@myfiledraft
\DeclareOption{draft}{\@myfiledrafttrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\if@myfiledraft
  \newcommand{\myterm}[1]{\emph{#1}\marginpar{TERM: #1}}
\else
  \newcommand{\myterm}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\fi

\endinput
```

If a document does

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{mymacros}

\begin{document}
\myterm{foo}
\end{document}
```

then "TERM: foo" will be written in the margin. If `draft` is removed, the same source will only emphasize "foo" in the text.

Comment: And is `\input{myfile}\input{myfile}` equivalent to `\usepackage{myfile}\usepackage{myfile}`?

Comment: @AndrewStacey You have a point!

Comment: Didn’t you miss a `\relax` behind `\ProcessOptions*`? I thought it’s god style to use it but forgot why …

Comment: @Tobi Actually I wanted to type `\ProcessOptions\relax`; when there's the `*` you don't need `\relax`, because the `*` stops `\@ifstar`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `\include` is so bad?

Comment: @tparker `\include` should only be used in the `document` environment, for big chunks of text, typically a unit like a chapter. Remember it issues a page break.

Answer (score 16):

You may put "library" code into `.tex` files and use `\input` instead of `\usepackage`, but then to give package options you'd have to define some variables. This would looks worse and you can do more mistakes.

Comment: "library code" implies code with "internal" definitions, using the `@` sign in command names.  when a `.sty` file is read in with `\usepackage`, `@` is automatically assumed to be a letter (so it can be used in a command name), and its status is converted back to "other" (a non-letter) when the `.sty` file is exited.

Comment: In addition by using a package you get automatic setting of `@` and access to the version control `\usepackage{mypkg}[2013/01/01]` to ensure that you get this year's version of your package..

Answer (score 7):

A minor point from a very practical point of view: Certain tools such as [fig2pdf](http://www.few.vu.nl/~wkager/fig2pdf.htm) allow to specify a list of packages to be loaded. This is done with `\usepackage`, thus the `.sty` ending is required for personal adjustments.