# How do I create an index?

Tags: memoir, indexing

How can I create an index with the `memoir` document class? I always get an error message.

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage[polutonikogreek, latin, english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\FunctionF(#1){(#1)^3- 3*(#1)}%
\usepackage{url}



\floatstyle{boxed} 
\restylefloat{figure} 


\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungen}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black, bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=20mm,bottom=20mm}

\OnehalfSpacing

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{lyhne}

%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily\raggedright}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{November 2016}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{plain}{\underline{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}}{}{\underline{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}}
\makeoddhead{plain}{\underline{Schweizer Jugend Forscht}}{}{\underline{Potz Blitz - Gewitter in Theorie und Praxis}}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents


\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! That is quite a large preamble, if possible, it would be helpful if you could trim it down a little bit. See [this post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for advice

Comment: There's no hint on how you are trying to make an index in the first place.

Comment: `10.5pt` is not a valid option for `memoir`.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example for generating an index with class `memoir`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
Hello\index{hello} world\index{world}!

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Then run LaTeX, `makeindex`, and LaTeX.

Result (page 3):

> [image: Result, page 3]

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) of class `memoir` explains the index stuff in section "17.2 Index".

Answer (score 1):

As @Heiko Oberdiek pointed out, even if you had everything else working, you did not initiate the index creation with `\makeindex`, insert and indexed`\index{index}` term, or use the `\printindex` command to create the index.   Then you still have to go through the process of running LaTeX, `makeindex` and LaTeX again.

The other problem you may be having is a preamble that is simply too big.  I have encountered this problem before on some of the documents I created with a large number of packages and customized styles.  The solution was to move the information I did not plan on changing, especially the stylistic information, into a `*.sty` file.  [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91167/why-use-sty-files) excellent question has a lot of information about `*.sty` files.  The nice thing is that the coding is the same, you just put all the preamble into another file and include it in your main document—both files are cleaner and work better as a result.

Comment: You don't mean to suggest that having 'too big' a preamble will cause your attempt to index to fail, do you? As for the first paragraph, I think this may work better as a comment.

Comment: I have had documents fail to process because the preamble, especially the style definition changes, exceeded the limit for a `*.tex` file. That would explain the OP statement of the file not processing at all.

Comment: I'm very surprised to hear that, and I can't help but wonder if it wasn't rather due to some other problems, such as (e.g.) loading packages twice with conflicting options.