# Include title in header using subfiles

Tags: fancyhdr, subfiles

I split my LaTeX document into subfiles and I try to have the title in the header, using `\fancyhead`. I define `\thetitle` in my cover file called "cover.tex", which I reproduced in the MWE below

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\title{This is my title}
\author{My Name}

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\theauthor}
\fancyhead[L]{\thetitle}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\Large \thetitle\\
\normalsize \theauthor\\
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

I use it in a main file like this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfiles} % split the document in multiple files
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\subfile{cover}
\newpage
Here I will include my text from multiple subfiles.
\end{document}
```

I get the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\f@nch@olh ->\thetitle
                       \strut
```

I identified the problem to be within the `subfiles`. I noticed that I don't get the error, if I put the content of the "cover.tex" file directly into the main file. But for readability I would like to avoid doing that. I also tried placing the `\fancyhead[L]{\thetitle}` line in the main document, which produced the same error.

I assume that the problem is within propagating the `\thetitle` variable throughout subfiles. My question is, how can I best place the title in the header without defining it multiple times and without moving the complete "cover.tex" into the main file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you use a header file (containing the preamble, packages you load, ...) with `\input`? You could put everything before \begin{document} into it and just load it via `\input{yourfile}`.

Comment: From `subfiles` manual, p. 2: “If the subordinated file was `\subfile`’d, it ignores anything before and including `\begin{document}`…”.  Indeed, your `\let\thetitle\@title` etc. declarations are placed *before* `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @nox I am actually using a `pgstyle.sty` file, containing the preamble and packages I load. Moving the part `\title` and `\makeatletter...` to that file solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: Hm, I don't recommend you to set the title in a style file, because a style file should be general enough to use it for other documents as well. It's probably better to use another file and load it with `\input` containing the title and specific stuff for your document.

Comment: I’d also suggest that you read carefully the contents of section 2.3 of the manual of the `subfiles` package, especially the part that says that “each subfile is `\input` within a group”…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a recommendation:

```
%% main.tex
\input{preamble}

% start of main document
\begin{document}
\input{cover}

Here I will include my text from multiple (sub)files.
\end{document}


%% preamble.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{subfiles} % split the document in multiple files
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\author{My Name}
\title{This is my title}
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\@author}
\fancyhead[L]{\@title}
\makeatother


%% cover.tex
\begin{titlepage}
  \Large \thetitle\\
  \normalsize \theauthor\\
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: That looks very neat. But your `preamble.tex` file looks very much like my `pgstyle.sty` file. Could you explain why one or the other is better? Or what belongs in which one?

Comment: @rome in latex, a style file is usually loaded via `\usepackage` and provides functionality for multiple documents rather than just one document, e.g., via optional arguments or general macros. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91167/why-use-sty-files