# Memoir multiple table of contents: undefined error

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, undefined

This is my first post and I am a relatively new user so I hope my question is not too trivial, I searched to see if this problem had been solved elsewhere but could not find anything. I am beginning to format my PhD thesis so that it is out the way in good time and not a concern in the future. I have read through the relevant sections of the documentation, I am not sure if it is because I am new that I cannot see the answer in the documents.

For the problem, when directly copying and pasting code provided in the [memoir documentation](https://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (pages 203-205, section 9.2.5)  to create different short and detailed table of contents, I am running into the following error:

```
Redoing nameref's sectioning
Redoing nameref's label
(./minworkingexampl.out) (./minworkingexampl.out)

! LaTeX Error: Command \cftpartformatpnum undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \setupshorttoc
                                % This section is copied directly from pg. 203-205 fr...
```

A slightly minimum .tex example to produce the error is:

```
% Minimum working example for ! LaTeX Error: Command \cftpartformatpnum undefined.

\documentclass{memoir} 
\usepackage{Minworkingexample}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}           % Included hyperref: a) in case it was causing errors, b) hyperlink the TOC's

\begin{document}

\setupshorttoc              % This section is copied directly from pg. 203-205 from the `The memoir class'
\tableofcontents*               % documentation PDF. 
\clearpage
\setupparasubsecs
\setupmaintoc
\tableofcontents*
\setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}        % pg. 205 `The memoir class' PDF documentation
\newpage

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\subsection{Intro}
\blindtext
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The .sty file used is `\usepackage{Minworkingexample}`:

```
% Minimum working example for ! LaTeX Error: Command \cftpartformatpnum undefined.

% This code is copied directly from pg. 203-205 from the `The memoir class' documentation PDF

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{Minworkingexample}[2021/06/28 Example package]

\newcommand*{\setupshorttoc}{%
    \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{Short contents}
    \let\oldchangetocdepth\changetocdepth
    \renewcommand*{\changetocdepth}[1]{}
    \let\oldprecistoctext\precistoctext
    \renewcommand{\precistoctext}[1]{}
    \let\oldcftchapterfillnum\cftchapterfillnum
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{0}% chapters and above
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\hfill\sffamily}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{ \textperiodcentered\space}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
    \setpnumwidth{0em}
    \setpnumwidth{1.5em}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{%
        {\cftchapterleader}\nobreak
        \hbox to 1.5em{\cftchapterpagefont ##1\hfil}\cftchapterafterpnum\par}
    \setrmarg{0.3\textwidth}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\@tocrmarg}
    \addtolength{\unitlength}{1.5em} % Add curly brace here before %, comment the code below out and no error is produced.
    
    %The code below is what is causing the issues with \cftpartformatpnum
    
    \let\oldcftpartformatpnum\cftpartformatpnum
    \renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{%
        \hbox to\unitlength{{\cftpartpagefont ##1}}}
    \let\oldcftbookformatpnum\cftbookformatpnum
    \renewcommand*{\cftbookformatpnum}[1]{%
        \hbox to\unitlength{{\cftbookpagefont ##1}}}}

    %The code above is what is causing the issues \cftpartformatpnum

%%% The code below seems to work correctly and has no issues
%%% so I believe it can be ignored. Needs to be included in this though I think

\newcommand*{\setupparasubsecs}{%
    \let\oldnumberline\numberline
    \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionfont}{\itshape}
    \renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionpagefont}{\itshape}
    \renewcommand{\l@subsection}[2]{%
        \def\numberline####1{\textit{####1}~}%
        \leftskip=\cftsubsectionindent
        \rightskip=\@tocrmarg
        \parfillskip=\fill
        \ifhmode ,\ \else\noindent\fi
        \ignorespaces
    {\cftsubsectionfont ##1}~{\cftsubsectionpagefont##2}%
    \let\numberline\oldnumberline\ignorespaces}
    }
\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\par}}

\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
    \let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
    \let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext
    \let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum
    \addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
        \sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}
    \setpnumwidth{2.55em}
    \setrmarg{3.55em}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
    \let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum
        \addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}
    \let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum
        \addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}
```

I placed the macros in a .sty file as they contained @ symbols and it was recommended by [egreg in another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91167/why-use-sty-files). I think this is appropriate to do but any thoughts on this would be appreciated. If I just keep pushing [enter] through the error then both ToC's load properly, but I don't want there to be issues with my code in the future and would prefer for it to be error free.

I would appreciate any help in regards to this issue and any advice about my post, have I included enough etc would also be appreciated, thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly which version of the manual are you copying from? In current version of the memoir manual page 203-205 has nothing to do with ToC and friends.

You have en error in

```
\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
    \let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
    \let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext
    \let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum
    \addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
        \sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}
    \setpnumwidth{2.55em}
    \setrmarg{3.55em}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}} % <---- error
    \let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum
        \addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}
    \let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum
        \addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}
```

The last `}` on the `tocdepth` line should be moved to the end

```
\newcommand*{\setupmaintoc}{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}
    \let\changetocdepth\oldchangetocdepth
    \let\precistoctext\oldprecistoctext
    \let\cftchapterfillnum\oldcftchapterfillnum
    \addtodef{\cftchapterbreak}{\par}{}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
        \sffamily\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
    \renewcommand*{\cftchapterafterpnum}{}
    \renewcommand{\cftchapterbreak}{\par\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}}
    \setpnumwidth{2.55em}
    \setrmarg{3.55em}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \let\cftpartformatpnum\oldcftpartformatpnum
        \addtodef{\cftpartbreak}{\par}{}
    \let\cftbookformatpnum\oldcftbookformatpnum
        \addtodef{\cftbookbreak}{\par}{}
}
```

When that `}` sits in the wrong place we end up setting `\cftpartformatpnum` to an undefined macro, and one cannot do `\renewcommand` on an undefined macro.

Comment: I was referring to the PDF pages of the memoir manual and not the page numbers at the bottom of the page, sorry. That's worked perfectly, thank you for your help, I wouldn't have guessed the error was in the last part but I know for the future to check all the code now.

Comment: @LaccaseTrametesVersicolor it does seem to be a typo. I'll make sure it is fixed in the next release

Comment: I appreciate it, thank you for maintaining the memoir class it is perfect for a thesis.

Comment: @LaccaseTrametesVersicolor that is what I keep telling our students